# How to load .tif raster files in R

Tags: r, tiff, magic-numbers

I am currently working on some raster models. My code has generated about 4k models (all .tif files), but about 10% of these cannot be opened using `load("insert path")`. I have tried `readr()`, `readRDS()` and `source()`, none of which worked. I have also reran some models but it didn't fix the problem. Why can't I load my .tif files?

```
load("comparison/mc45bi50/ni1130region33.tif")
```

> Error in load("comparison/mc45bi50/ni1130region33.tif") :    bad
> restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded In
> addition: Warning message: file ‘ni1130region33.tif’ has magic number
> 'II*'   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

```
source("comparison/mc45bi50/ni1130region33.tif")
```

> Error in source("comparison/mc45bi50/ni1130region33.tif") :
> comparison/mc45bi50/ni1130region33.tif:2:0: unexpected end of input 1:
> II*

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `raster` library. It has the `raster()` function, which should read your .tif file.

Example, creating a raster ourselves, and saving it on disk, Then  try to read:

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

## create raster
r <-  raster(ncols=3, nrows=3)
r[] <- 1:9

# save to disk
tmp <- paste(tempdir(), "myraster.tif", sep = "/")
writeRaster(r, tmp)

## read now
r <- raster(tmp)
```