# How can I modify a .tiff file with R

Tags: r, matrix, tiff

I have to read some tif files and modify them by rotating, cutting or inversing them.
I figured out how to import my file and I can modify it by translating the data into a matrix but now I don't know how to make a tif file with the information I stored into this matrix.

I searched for a while but it seems that nobody asked this so, could someone give me some ideas to complete this task pls?

Here is my code.

```
rotation = function(Matrice){
  res = matrix(c(rep(NA, length(Matrice))), nrow = ncol(Matrice), ncol = nrow(Matrice))
  for (i in 1:nrow(Matrice)){
    res[,(nrow(Matrice) - i + 1)] = Matrice[i,]
  }
  return(res)
}

photo = readTIFF("../DataSqueletted/1.tif")
photo2 = matrix(photo, ncol = 1280, nrow = 960)
photo2 = rotation(photo2)
```

"photo" is a large array while "photo2" is a matrix butwhen i type "View(photo)" i've got the exact same structure.

Comment: why not just work with `raster()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814806/how-to-load-tif-raster-files-in-r

Comment: ... or delegate the image manipulation for something designed for image manipulation?  Like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).  The structure of a TIFF file is not straightforward...

Comment: Also, if you install ImageMagick on your computer, you can access it through R with the `magick` package.